# Microsoft Dynamics CRM: Export solution from 2015 to 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm

Is it possible to export a solution from CRM 2015 (7.0) to CRM 2013 (6.1)? Instructions I've found online say there's a step to choose target version in the export wizard but it doesn't appear for me.

Comment: It looks like you can only choose the target version from 7.1 to 7.0 or from 6.1 to 6.0, but not from 7.x to 6.x: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn689055.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not possible. The only way is manual copying of solution.

Answer (score 3):

Andrii is right, there doesn't seem to be a way to import a 2015 solution into 2013. But at least in my case, I was able get an import to work by unzipping and editing XML files in the exported solution. Perhaps this could help someone else:

In `solution.xml` I set `version="6.1.3.125"` and `SolutionPackageVersion="6.1"` in the initial `<ImportExportXml>` element.

Then using regex find and replace in Notepad++ I removed the following elements throughout `customizations.xml` to make the schema match:

- `<SourceType>`
- `<CanChangeHierarchicalRelationship>`
- `<EntityHelpUrlEnabled>`
- `<EntityHelpUrl>`
- `<IsHierarchical>`

Zipped the files back up and it successfully imported into 2013.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to hack the solution files and successfully imported a 2015 Update 1 solution into 2013.  Here were my steps:

Change the first line of solution.xml to the following:

Remove the following from customizations.xml (obviously these reference new features not yet available back in 2013)
    0
    0
    0
    1
    0
    ….. 
    …..
    0
    1
    0
    0
    0
    1
    false
    1
    0
    5.0.0.0
    1.0.0.0
    1.0
    1.0.5.418
Replace
    
with
    
Remove IntroducedVersion="5.0.0.0" from SiteMap area

Edit all Workflow XML files
Change Version=7.0.0.0 to Version=5.0.0.0